# What am I doing wrong in this gsub example?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

[I'm looking at this tutorial for using RegEx with `stringr`](https://github.com/gimoya/theBioBucket-Archives/blob/master/R/RegEx_Examples.R). Using the below example:

```
str <- c("i.e., George W. Bush", "Lyndon B. Johnson, etc.")
gsub("([A-Z])[.]?", "\\1", str)
```

The tutorial tells me the output will generate:

```
[1] "George W Bush"    "Lyndon B Johnson"
```

But then I run an identical script on R and this is what happens:

```
str <- c("i.e., George W. Bush", "Lyndon B. Johnson, etc.")
gsub("([A-Z])[.]?", "\\1", str)
[1] "i.e., George W Bush"    "Lyndon B Johnson, etc."
```

It simply returns the original text. Even when I run it on one of the Regex tester sites it still spits back the same thing.

[image: From https://regex101.com/]

Am I doing something wrong (likely)? Or is the tutorial wrong (doubtful)? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here (confirmed).

Comment: the tutorial is wrong. unless "i.e.," and "etc." were not meant to be in the strings `gsub("([A-z]+)[.]?", "\\1", c("George W. Bush", "Lyndon B. Johnson"))`

Comment: rawr has the answer. 

I highly suggest https://regexone.com as a little tutorial on learning regex. It is platform independant (mostly), so this knowledge can be transferred to any language.

Comment: Oh, I know Regex pretty well. It was more just for the tutorial on `gsub` that I ended up there. I love it, for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're doing is right and there is in fact a mistake in the tutorial. I tested the regex too, you can see [it here](https://regex101.com/r/cs8MMs/1). What the regex you are given is capturing any uppercase letter that may or may not be followed by a dot. For instance, "W." in "George W. Bush" is substituted with "W", but "i.e." is not captured and substituted because none of the characters are capitalized. If we had "I.E." it would get substituted with "IE". In order to capture the names given we need a different regex. One approach might be to capture the first name, middle initial, and last name. Now you could get the effect with the regex `.*([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z])[.]+\s([A-Z][a-z]+).*` see [here](https://regex101.com/r/cs8MMs/2) or in R using

```
str <- c("i.e., George W. Bush", "Lyndon B. Johnson, etc.")
gsub(".*([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z])[.]+ ([A-Z][a-z]+).*", "\\1 \\2 \\3", str)
#> [1] "George W Bush"    "Lyndon B Johnson"
```

But that's probably not the most effective to go to sanitize a some names.